# What Unicode is allowed in domain names under ccTLDs?

Tags: domains, top-level-domains, cctld

Western Somoa, Equilateral Ginuea, and some other countries don't use the IDN2008 protocol and allow Unicode including Emoji; something IDN2008 doesn't allow.

I've been trying to figure out what creative Unicode names I could register under these TLDs but try as I might, I can't find the documentation for them.

I've tried asking WebSite.ws for documentation but they've responded with:

> Unfortunately there is no additional information about punycode allowed. Emoji domains and internationalized domain names that use punycode are allowed within our domain name registration parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.WS is a very specific case, with very few others not following IDNA2008 (while some others may still be on IDNA2003 or not accepting IDNs at all).

(Wikipedia says there are 8 TLDs in that case, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji_domain while https://xn--i-7iq.ws/#tlds claims that only .WS accepts them but speaks also about .LA in their history. YMMV)

This website (https://www.dnacademy.com/emoji-domains) says that .WS now supports the Emoji 5.0 standard, so all characters in it.

Also on https://www.worldsite.ws/idn-orderflow/index.dhtml?view=advanced if you look at the form at bottom on the left you have the scripts allowed so one can imagine you can use all characters in these scripts.

This rules out special characters like spacers, modifiers, etc. that should not be accepted if there is no bug.

Comment: While you did not exactly answer my question, I got the gist of it with "It seems to only accept emojis + language characters". I did not come to a great conclusion following that wikipedia article. There are absolutely no unicode restrictions on subdomains. meaning I was able to create a right-to-left embed as part of a link, looks like this- ‫.www.‫.stackoverflow.com
Which looks like not a valid link but it totally is. Was wondering if you could add this information to your post.

Comment: It's funny because it actually breaks once I post it. Hopefully this screenshot explains what I meant: https://i.imgur.com/M3fCrt6.png

Comment: From my research I came indeed to the conclusion that it would be emoji+some scripts, but since there is no official documentation I couldn't be 100% sure. As for subdomains, what you see is normal: once you register a domain name you control everything below, so you are your own master there and can decide if you implement IDNA2003, 2008 or something else (DNS is 8 bit clean, technically you could put any unicode character there).... but of course you are still constrained by software used by your users.

Comment: With the right-to-left you used, your comment is displayed strangely :-)

Answer (score 0):

Every ccTLD can create their own rules, so you aren't going to find a standard about what is used.

What I might do if I were trying to do what you are, is just type paste the emoji into either the search tool at the Registry site or into a unicode converter.

Example, if I wanted to find out what 6 hearts converted to, I'd go to website.ws and use their emoticon icon on the search bar to punch that in and see what unicode spits out.  ❤❤❤❤❤❤.ws ---> xn--qeiaaaaa.ws

Comment: I know every ccTLD creates their own rules, I'd just like to see those rules for at least one of them. I'm not trying to register a emoji domain but rather an exploitative unicode, such as xn--wvg which is unicode for right-to-left override.